# How to expand my table view cell?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uitouch

Using this code to expand the table view cell,but its not working for me.I know there is some thing wrong in this code help me to find out.

```
![selectindex = -1;

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

}
-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView

{

    return 1;
}
-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return  \[Arr_lbl count\];
}
#pragma mark table cell creating and loading the data
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    AntzclubCell *cell=\[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Antz"\];
    cell.img_antzClub.image=\[UIImage imageNamed:\[Arr_img objectAtIndex:indexPath.row\]\];
    cell.lbl_antzClub.text=\[Arr_lbl objectAtIndex:indexPath.row\];
    cell.accessoryType=UITableViewCellAccessoryDetailDisclosureButton;
    cell.backgroundColor=\[UIColor blackColor\];
    return  cell;
}
#pragma mark expanding height
-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if(selectindex==indexPath.row){
        return 400;
    }
    else{
        return 132;
    }

}
#pragma mark user selecting option
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (indexPath.row==selectindex) {

        selectindex=-1;
        \[tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:\[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath\] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade\];
        return;
    }
        if(selectindex !=-1)
        {
            NSIndexPath *prepath=\[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:selectindex inSection:0\];
            selectindex=indexPath.row;
            \[tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:\[NSArray arrayWithObject:prepath\] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationLeft\];
        }
        selectindex=indexPath.row;
        \[tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:\[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath\] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade\];
    }]
```

[image]
this image is my output while i click the cell its merged with other data not expanding.

Comment: every cell have different height??

Comment: yes different height but now i implemented same height for each cell.

Comment: so you can use external api class which is helps you. you can use external api class in your app or copy external api code in your app.

Comment: can you send me the link ....if it is possible.

Comment: please download from this link https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/skstableview

Comment: you got your question's answer.

Comment: yes bro i got and i seen your requested link that kind of implementation also i need thanks to guide me to achieve my query..

Comment: i going to use two custom cell in a single table view now ....send your email id i will send the link to you while i am asking doubts..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83822/discussion-between-kishore-kumar-and-sandy-patel).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on the versions of iOS you want to support the answer may differ, but it seems you didn't implement `heightForRowAtIndexPath:`

Comment: i am implemented the estimated height for row at index path is any thing wrong in my code please mention that.

Comment: You need to implement `heightForRowAtIndexPath:` yes your code is wrong because you did not implement it and you did not show that you were using self-sizing cells.

Comment: i implemented the heightForRowAtIndexPath now expanding but some of the other cell are expanding but label has been merged ....

Comment: so now i understand n number of custom cell we can implement in our table view .....